# CSS: Id and classes not working as intended?

Tags: html, css

In my code below my id and classes are not being shown on my page (i.e the color green etc), how do I solve this?

They were both working before until I added the div and now it does not work.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title> CSS </title>

    <style type="text/css">


        <!-- Note the . which refers to a class -->
        .large{
        font-size:300%;
        }

        <!-- Note the # which refers to a single id -->
        #green{
        color:green;
        }

        .underline{
        text-decoration:underline;
        }

        .bold{

        font-weight:bold;

        }

        div {

        background-color:blue;

        }



    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> Example heading </h1>

    <div>

        <p class="large"> This is a bit of text </p>

    </div>

    <p id="green" class="large"> A bit more... </p>

    <!-- Note how it's possible to refer to 3 classes at the one time, seperated by spaces -->
    <p> The third <span class= "underline large bold">word</span> in this paragraph is underlined. </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know, it's possible that the html comments inside the style are making invalid  .large and #green

Comment: you basically saying "i'm too lazy to take 30 minutes to properly learn CSS, please teach me now". a minimum knowledge should be obtained before asking a question.

Comment: I understand why you would think that but I was genuinely unsure what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a silly problem, took me a while to understand it because I was looking for something else!

The problem are the comments. In CSS you comment with

`/* comment */`

and not `<!-- -->` like in HTML. Just modify the comments and it should works without problems.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp